# iOS Build failed with IOException

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I started with Unity since a few days and I want to run my game SNAKE on iPad. But on iOS Builds, I get the following error:

```
IOException: Failed to Copy File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea/Trampoline/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' to '/Users/markusunger/Desktop/Snake-iOS/Snake-iOS/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'.
UnityEditor.iOS.Utils.ReplaceFileOrDirectoryCopy (System.String src, System.String dst)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.UpdateInstallLocation (UnityEditor.iOS.ProjectPaths paths, ScriptingImplementation backend, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.iOS.IncludedFileList includedFiles)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor pp, BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String stagingAreaDataManaged, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Anybody an idea? I get the error with both scripting backend...

I have Mac OS 10.10.5 and xCode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Thanks for help!

Comment: What version of Unity?  Did you use *Replace* or *Append* when generating the Xcode project?  Was Xcode open when you did this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error in two conditions:

- I did an `Append` during a build.
- I had lack of space in my HDD.

Using `Replace` in unity build and making some space in HDD, fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem today:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/<username>/Code/<appname>/Temp/StagingArea/Trampoline/LaunchScreen-iPhone.xib".
```

Using *Replace* instead of *Append* solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This us a bug in Unity. It's fixed in 2017.3.0f3.

[Bug Details](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-appending-builds-with-different-target-devices-results-in-filenotfoundexception-for-launch-image-files)